# org.json.JSONException: Value <div of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject during the debugging

Tags: java, android, json, jsonexception

```
I develope android application ,one of my concept is pass user rating of an android  application

all are required paramter to pass ratelogin asynchronus ,
 When i run my  Android application i got the Exception during the debugging  my application ,i gave my exception  below,please any one give the solution for this problem..thanks in advance.

**My exception is** 

>org.json.JSONException: Value <div of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

MyActiviy:
    //where the paramater passed to RateLogin asynchronus task

```
new rateLogin().execute(userid, Strbookid,userrating, Deviceid);

//Asychronus task for ratelogin 

class rateLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String userid = "";
    String Strbookid = "";
    String userRating="";
    String Deviceid = "";
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        userid = strings[0];
        Strbookid = strings[1];
        userRating=strings[2];
        Deviceid = strings[3];
```

/*Rate login : XMl Http Post
      Here   login user id,Book id, application rate for user given,  mobile device id
    */
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     // Creating HTTP Post

```
        HttpPost httpPost = null;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = null;
            httpPost = new HttpPost(
                Rateurl);
        // Building post parameters and  key and value pair
        nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookid", Strbookid));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userrating", userRating));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", Deviceid));
        // Url Encoding the POST parameters and  writing error to Log
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        // Making HTTP Request to user rating value
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
try
{
//this line only got Exception
            String strRet = HttpHelper.request(response);
   // writing exception to log of Rate login
}catch(Exception e)

}

            Log.d(strRet, "strstrRet");

            JSONObject jsonObjRecv=null;

                    jsonObjRecv  = new JSONObject(strRet);
                String result = jsonObjRecv.getString("status");
                String message = jsonObjRecv.getString("info");
                if (result.equals("Success")) {
                    showalert(message);
} 
           else {
                    showalert(message);
                }
        return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: any one give the solution,,thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think you are getting wrong response from server. If you debug app you find that your response is something like this

I have faced same problem. So its server error not android.....